# Another grep advanced

Tags: unix, search, grep

Q1. I want to grep something like that:

```
grep -Ir --exclude-dir="some*dirs" "my-text" ~/somewhere
```

but I don't want to show the whole strings containing "my-text", I want to see only list of files.

Q2. I want to see list of files containing "my-text" but not containing "another-text". How to do that?

Sorry, but I could not find the answer in man grep, neither in google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1. You mustn't have googled very hard on that one.

[`man grep`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep)

> -l, --files-with-matches
>           Suppress normal output; instead print the  name  of  each  input
>           file  from  which  output would normally have been printed.  The
>           scanning will stop on the first match.

Q2. Unless you expect both patterns to be on the same line, you'll need multiple invocations of grep.  Something like:

```
$ grep -l my-text | xargs grep -vl another-text
```

Comment: "Q1. You mustn't have googled very hard on that one." – Yep, looks like that... Thanks

Comment: But I still have this problem... When these 2 search cases "happen" on different lines. E.g. a file with 2 strings:
**wp_123\nwp3_123**, 
`grep -lr wp_ ~/tmp | xargs grep -vl wp3_`
outputs this file!
But if I remove line break, it's ok, it doesn't output.

Comment: Anybody here? :) I've the question [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960494/grep-xargs-grep-with-search-conditions-on-different-strings).