# "grep | xargs grep" with search conditions on different strings

Tags: unix, search, grep

I want to grep files that contain text "wp_" but do not contain text "wp3_". E.g. I've got a file with two strings:

> wp_123
>
> wp3_123

I try `$ grep -lr wp_ ~/tmp | xargs grep -vl wp3_`

It outputs this file name! But if I remove the linebreak, it's working like I want, i.e. handles string "wp_123 wp3_123" correctly.

How to make it work with search conditions on different strings?

P.S. Sorry for kind of duplicate, but seems that nobody noticed [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959666/another-grep-advanced#comment-14308071) during last hour...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
$ grep -lr 'wp_' ~/tmp | xargs grep -L 'wp3_'
```

The single quotes are not necessary in this case, but are a good habit to prevent pattern characters from being interpreted by the shell. In your original attempt, -vl means "print each file with at least one line that does not match". Here, -L means "print each file with no lines that match".